# How to find out if time is in sequence in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, time

I have a table containing some Timespans (as two `TIME` columns)

Eg:

```
TimeBegin        TimeEnd
---------------- ----------------
00:00:00.0000000 01:00:00.0000000
01:00:00.0000000 02:00:00.0000000
01:30:00.0000000 03:00:00.0000000
```

I need to figure out whether the timespans form a sequence (in the above case from 00.00 - 03.00). Some of the timespans might overlap, as is the case above.

**Edit**
I extended my table to:

```
WeekDay     TimeBegin        TimeEnd
----------- ---------------- ----------------
3           00:00:00.0000000 01:00:00.0000000
3           01:00:00.0000000 02:00:00.0000000
3           02:30:00.0000000 04:00:00.0000000
```

and used the query:

```
;with sequenced as (
    select *,rn=ROW_NUMBER() over (order by timebegin)
    from tbl
    where weekday(timebegin) = 2)
select *
from sequenced a
join sequenced b on a.rn=b.rn-1
where a.TimeEnd < b.TimeBegin
```

but it says ''weekday' is not a recognized built-in function name.'

so I changed it to:

```
;with sequenced as (
    select *,rn=ROW_NUMBER() over (order by timebegin)
    from tbl
    where weekday = 2)
select *
from sequenced a
join sequenced b on a.rn=b.rn-1
where a.TimeEnd < b.TimeBegin
```

but then it returns the row containing

```
WeekDay TimeBegin   TimeEnd
3        01:00:00.0000000   02:00:00.0000000
```

which is actually in the sequence?

thanks
Thomas

Comment: and what is the expected output?? Just a "yes - it's a sequence" or what?? Should the rows that cause conflicts be listed? Or those that neatly form a sequence?? You need to be a bit more specific!

Comment: Hi marc_s. Sorry about that. I only need true or false for the entire sequence. Thanks

Comment: I highly suggest you discover an ORM. If I made a prison for programmers I would torture them by forcing them to write complex TSQL.

Comment: @Nick, you might be right. Maybe I would be better of writing this in c# rather than complex TSQL, which I have a hard time figuring out

Comment: Your edited question shows rows for day=3, but the query is day=2. That aside, the sequence is broken at between 2 and 2:30, which is why it is shown in my result?

Comment: @Nick maybe for trivial queries yes. If we were inspecting 100,000 rows of data to find gaps, you want to suck all of that into C# and do it there? There is a reason for database systems

Comment: @Richard, If you wrote the query in LINQ to SQL, LINQ would translate the query into TSQL as if you wrote it in TSQL. The difference is you can write it in less code with LINQ, while getting intellisense, and it's easier to write. I think you are mistaking my previous comment for ADO.SUCK. Which, is not what I'm speaking of.

Comment: @Nick I haven't checked Google recently, but has LINQ solved all the parameter sniffing problems, or auto-generation of complex SQL problems (as in non-performant)? Not being facetious, but I am really interested to know if LINQ is really up to scratch for every job possibly contrived.

Comment: @Richard, LINQ to SQL is a great tool to use, but it does have it's limitations. For most people it handles everything they need, but if you need more flexibility I suggest looking into NHibernate. I'm not sure if the problems you mentioned have been fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This checks **EVERY** single record in the table in time order, and shows ALL the gaps.  If there are no records shown, then you have no gaps == the data forms an unbroken sequence

```
;with sequenced as (
    select *,rn=ROW_NUMBER() over (order by timebegin) from tbl)
select *
from sequenced a
join sequenced b on a.rn=b.rn-1
where a.TimeEnd < b.TimeBegin
```

Assuming this is a timetable (only a week's data) and you only want to check within a specific day, you can use

```
;with sequenced as (
    select *,rn=ROW_NUMBER() over (order by timebegin)
    from tbl
    where weekday(timebegin) = 2)
select *
from sequenced a
join sequenced b on a.rn=b.rn-1
where a.TimeEnd < b.TimeBegin
```

But it covers only the records that `begin on weekday 2 (Monday)` and any time spans that cross midnight are not considered.

If this covers MULTIPLE weeks and you need to check EACH Monday, then it gets more complicated.

```
;with sequenced as (
    select *,
           Date = DateDiff(d,0,timebegin),
           rn   = ROW_NUMBER() over (order by timebegin)
    from tbl
    where weekday(timebegin) = 2)
select *
from sequenced a
join sequenced b on a.rn = b.rn-1 and a.Date = b.Date
where a.TimeEnd < b.TimeBegin
```

Comment: note that this assumes that the rows are in order, i.e. `TimeBegin` for row `i` is always smaller than `TimeBegin` for row `i+1`

Comment: Hi Richard, it works - thanks! Is it a problem with the ordering since the query orders by timebegins, and I guess it takes care of the ordering issue? If I need to extend the table with additional columns (eg. weekday as an int) and I wish to use the additional columns in my where-clause, would I then do something like a.WeekDay=1 or would I have to include both a.WeekDay=1 and b.WeekDay=1? Thanks, Thomas

Comment: @user it really depends whether your where clause needs to be done AFTER detecting sequences, or BEFORE. It should normally go inside the sub-query

Comment: Continuing with the weekday-column, my table would look like: TimeBegin, TimeEnd, Weekday. I only want to evaluate timespans with weekday = 2 as a sequence. Would I then use "where a.TimeEnd < b.TimeBegin AND a.WeekDay=2" or "where a.TimeEnd < b.TimeBegin AND a.WeekDay=2 AND b.WeekDay=2". Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: @Richard, I cannot get your query to work. I have updated the question after trying your query

Answer (score 1):

since you only need `true` or `false` for the entire sequence, you can follow this algorithm:

```
1. sort the sequence in order of TimeBegin
2. put them in a temp table, include row_number
3. for every row starting with the second one:
    check if TimeBegin is smaller than or equal to the TimeEnd for the previous row
        if no, return false
4. return true
```

edit: just realized this fails in some weird cases like this:

```
TimeBegin        TimeEnd
---------------- ----------------
00:00:00.0000000 05:00:00.0000000
01:00:00.0000000 02:00:00.0000000
02:30:00.0000000 03:00:00.0000000
```

this should still count as a sequence (I think) and return `true`, but my algorithm doesn't account for this scenario.  To fix this, when inserting into the temp table, remove the records that are completely "contained" in the previous record (i.e. if `TimeBegin[i] > TimeBegin[i-1] and TimeEnd[i] < TimeEnd[i-1]`)